# Implement 'Undo' Swipe to remove from listview android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am using [romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss](https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss) to implement swipe to remove item from listview. Everything is working fine for me up till now as i want to implement the **undo** feature with this library. I have gone through the code and coudn't find any thing to help me with this thing. Can anyone please tell me how to implement this feature after removing item from listview.

**Code for swipe to remove**

```
 SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener touchListener =
            new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener(
                    favTalkshowList,
                    new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.DismissCallbacks() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean canDismiss(int position) {

                                return true;

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDismiss(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                            for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                                adapter.remove(position);
                            }
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                    });
    favTalkshowList.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);

    favTalkshowList.setOnScrollListener(touchListener.makeScrollListener());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a great library which does what I was looking to do!!

https://github.com/timroes/SwipeToDismissUndoList